# Laravel - Default vs Modular Approach

Tags: laravel

What's the recommendation on grouping your business logic in Laravel? I find Laravel to be quite messy when it comes to large web applications. Should we continue to use Laravel default file locations or have anyone tried using a modular package like https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules ?

Comment: I think this depends on the developer and their approach. I have a very structured approach but dont work modular. Just take a look at how you usually work and base the decision on that.

Comment: @Collin Thanks. Interested to hear the pros and cons from anyone who has used a modular package.

Answer (score 3):

Laravel is a fantastic platform, not only for its elegant syntax and rapid development tool, but also for its community and open source packages. These bundles go a long way toward reducing development time.

**Modules**

Modules are like packages in that they have their own Models, Views, Controllers, Migrations, and other classes.

All Controllers and Models are placed in the app/ folder by default in a Laravel program, while Migrations, Seeder, Providers, and other components have their own folder.
These folders become inconvenient when the application develops. It becomes difficult to locate logic for a specific portion of the application.

This is where using a modular approach to large projects simplifies production and maintenance. You can build different modules for different parts of your application using Modules. Each module has its own set of configuration options, such as controllers, models, views, migration, seeders, and providers.

To use modules in Laravel, simply autoload the Modules folder using PSR-4 and you're finished. However, this will entail additional tasks such as registering a namespace for language, views, and configuration, as well as running the migration.

**Laravel Modules**

- Installing Laravel Modules is similar to installing any other
  package.
- Laravel Modules provides Artisan Commands to create new Modules,
  activate/deactivate modules, create migrations. Below is a quick
  screenshot of the different artisan command it provides.
- When you create a new module it also registers a new custom namespace
  for Lang, View, and Config.

  Lang::get('blog::group.name');
  @trans('blog::group.name');
- Apart from these it also provides useful Facade Methods, Module
  Methods
- And also can publish your modules similar to a package (document).

**How we used Laravel Modules?**

Initially, when we started working on a pos (point of sale) application we didn’t have an idea of creating different modules.
But as the requirements increased to have a plug-play Restaurant extension for it, the idea of making modular made more sense.
So after creating and adding restaurants and many other optional modules, we added a setting for each business to enable or disable different modules.
Module::all(); method was used to list different modules the application had.
Each business can enable or disable modules for them as per their needs.
We used a combination of Module: has(‘blog’); business settings to check if a module is available & enabled.
The Module (or extension or plugin) can be put in any other application to add the functionality.